# How to instruct cypress to do some actions if the testcase is passed?

Tags: cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

I try to use aftereach() but it will execute either the testcase is passed or failed. I need to know the context of that should i use for example if condition or what?
For example:

```
describe('TestSuite', function(){

 it('THIS TEST CASE PASSED', function(){

})

it('THIS TEST CASE FAILED', function(){

})

})
```

I need to make it like this. If the a testcase is passed do the actions
...
...
...
and if the testcase failed do the actions
...
...
...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't give much info about your code, so I will suggest a solution that might not be suited for you. I would use a variable that gets set to "fail" if an assertion fails in the previous test and use that to determine the action in the 2nd test, e.g.

```js
describe('check if first test passed or failed then do A or B', () => {
    let result

    it('test 1', () => {
        cy.request({url: Cypress.env('url')}).its('status').then((status) => {
            if (status === 500) {
                result = 'fail'
            }
        })
    })

        it('test 2', () => {
            if (result === 'fail') {
                cy.log('Previous test failed, so I did Action A')
                Code Action A
            }
            else
            {
                cy.log('Previous test passed, so I did Action B')
                Code Action B
            }

        })
})
```